# MySql Workbench and Html Sublimetext 3

Tags: html, mysql

I have been writing SQL queries for a while now, but brand new to HTML.

I have been using Sublime text to code HTML and using Mysql - Workbench to code databases etc on local server.

I'm wondering..

How do I code HTML to return SQL queries onto a console (Google Chrome)? and connect the two together

I have searched all over google and You Tube, only thing I can find is something to do with PHP.. not sure what how it works, but don't think that is something I need.

All I want to do is create a text box inside HTML and input `id` value as an example `10` and return the `id` number along with the whole row from the database.

Using this query: `select * from tableName where id = 10;`

Comment: You can't. HTML/CSS is for display. You have to use a server-side language such as PHP, Node.js, Python or whatever.  You can use Javascript and AJAX requests to execute it so you don't have to do full page reloads.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, could you link me where I can get started with this? I have some knowledge on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a document formatting language. While it supports JavaScript, said JavaScript is sandboxed in the browser: It cannot easily access files and the like even when that other stuff is running on the same computer as the browser. The main reason here is security. Imagine every web page on the Internet could look at every file on your disk, copy them or save new files on your disk or modify them.

So what you need is a "server software" of some kind. This software talks to the browser. It sends it all the HTML that the browser requests. The HTML can then ask for more (for example using JavaScript and AJAX). These requests go to the server which parses the parameters, collects the data (only the server talks to the database) and sends results back.

This is a pretty complicated and involved process. For this reason, everyone uses a framework to do it. The framework handles all the ugly stuff like converting query results from the database into the types and objects of the programming language and then again to HTML code which looks good.

Since you don't know any programming languages, yet, I suggest you start with Python. A good web framework for Python is called "Django". Django also contains modules to talk to databases. It also has many "widgets" like tables that display query results.

Google for "python django mysql" which should give you plenty of examples.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I will not be hosting this website at all. Just doing it for purpose for local machine

Comment: Hosting is the only option. For the browser, there is no difference whether it's loading from `http://localhost/` or somewhere else. Note that you can run Django on your computer together with your browser. Every developer does that.